# Como usar o método POST em redirecionamentos (CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION) usando cURL?

Tags: php, libcurl

Estou enviando dados, através do `FORM/DATA` para outro servidor. No código, eu coloquei para ser enviado via POST. Porém, o POST não é enviado após o redirecionamento:

```
        $curl = curl_init($this->urlCreate);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $this->urlCreate);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        
        $headers = array(
            "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "Authorization: Bearer {$this->bear()}",
        );
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        
        $data = <<<DATA
            {
            "name_attendence": "12345",
            "cpf_attendence": "John Smith",
            "company_attendence": "1",
            "email_attendence": "10.00"
            }
            DATA;
            
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        
        $resp = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        // var_dump($resp);

        return ["danger", $resp];
```

O servidor me redireciona e retorna o seguinte cabeçalho:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently 
Date: Mon, 06 Jun 2022 13:28:16 GMT 
Server: Apache/2.4.47 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1k PHP/7.4.19 
Location: url.test/api/create-attendence 
Content-Length: 245 
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

Depois, me informa a seguinte menssagem:

```
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.
```

Como posso fazer para informar ao CURL que trabalhe com o método POST, mesmo após o redirecionamento?

Comment: O problema foi resolvido, link abaixa da solução https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22296828/php-curl-says-moved-permanently-when-posting-to-a-virtual-host

Comment: Eu alterei a sua pergunta para clarificar que se trata do redirecionamento, de forma que seja útil para outras pessoas. Caso acredite que a edição seja exagerada, ou não condiz com o que teve a interação de perguntar, você pode desfazer a edição (https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/555141/revisions). Você também pode adicionar uma resposta (como resposta) se a minha não responde de forma adequada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O seu código já é suposto a usar `POST`, uma vez que usa o `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true)`.

Porém, você também está usando `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true)`. Isso não faz sentido. Sempre que há um redirecionamento, o "POST" é removido.

---

Se quiser manter o `POST` no redirecionamento você precisa usar:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTREDIR, CURL_REDIR_POST_ALL);
```

> Isso exige cURL 7.19.1 ou superior e PHP 7.0.7 ou superior.

---

Uma outra coisa é tentar ver para onde está redicionando, habilitando os headers:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
```

Então vê para onde ele está redicionando, e utilizar o URL correto na requisição diretamente.

Comment: Ao habilitar esse CURLOPT_HEADER. ele me informa o seguinte:   HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently Date: Mon, 06 Jun 2022 13:28:16 GMT Server: Apache/2.4.47 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1k PHP/7.4.19 Location: http://url.test/api/create-attendence Content-Length: 245 Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

Comment: Então, existe um redirecionamento, e o problema é esse. O `CURLOPT_POSTREDIR`+ `CURL_REDIR_POST_ALL` irá definir o POST para essas rqeuisições redirecionadas. Ou usa esse link direto no `curl_init($this->urlCreate)`, de forma a evitar o redirecionamento.